# Failed when construct opencv cv::Mat using data of a gray image in poppler

Tags: opencv, poppler

When using `poppler::image::format_gray8`, it crashes due to memory access violation

```cpp
poppler::page * page = poppler_pdf_doc->create_page(page_index);
poppler::page_renderer page_render;
page_render.set_image_format(poppler::image::format_gray8);
poppler::image poppler_img = page_render.render_page(page, 120, 120);
cv::Mat(poppler_img.height(), poppler_img.width(), CV_8UC1, poppler_img.data(), poppler_img.bytes_per_row()).copyTo(__cv_mat_page);
```

But using `poppler::image::format_rgb24`, it's ok

```cpp
poppler::page * page = __poppler_pdf_doc->create_page(page_index);
poppler::page_renderer page_render;
page_render.set_image_format(poppler::image::format_rgb24);
poppler::image poppler_img = page_render.render_page(page, 120, 120);
cv::Mat(poppler_img.height(), poppler_img.width(), CV_8UC3, poppler_img.data(), poppler_img.bytes_per_row()).copyTo(__cv_mat_page);
```

Why?

BTW, any easy way to convert format `poppler::image::format_mono`(1 bit per pixel) to `cv::Mat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

poppler's mono image is 1 bit per pixel, and opencv's is 1 byte per pixel.